# Matching angle of a text to align with angle of regression line in an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering if there might be a way to set the `srt` (text rotation angle) argument of `text()` in R, such that the text generated by `text()` always has the **same angle** as the **angle of the regression line** in the plot (*see picture below*)?

Here is my R code:

```
plot.cor <- function(n){
x = 1:n
y = rnorm(n, 9)

plot(y~x, col = 4) 
abline(lm(y~x), col = 2)
text(mean(x), mean(y), paste0("r = ", round(cor(x,y), 3)), srt = 15, pos = 3, font = 2)
}
# Example of use:
plot.cor(30)  
plot.cor(30)
plot.cor(30)
```

[image]

Comment: See also [Rotated text on a regression line](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2008-May/163153.html)

Comment: @Henrik, got you many thanks.